# Image gallery default tab

Tags: html, css, gallery

I can't figure out how to make it so that landscapes is not the default tab. Whenever you hover off of the area it goes to landscapes, and even if you are on another tab, landscapes is always darker than the rest. Please help. The jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/jspence29/nQ2TK/. Thanks!
To be clear, I want it so that when you mouse off of the image gallery the tab that you were last on is up, not landscapes, and when you mouse over another to change the tab, that landscapes is the same color as the rest.

```
/* common styling */

#body a {color:#000;}
#body a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
#body a:visited {color:#000;}

/* slides styling */

#body .photo {width:635px; text-align:left; position:relative; margin:0 auto;}

#body .photo ul.topic {padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; width:635px; height:auto; position:relative; }

#body .photo ul.topic li {display:block; width:125px; height:31px; float:left;}
#body .photo ul.topic li a.set {display:block; font-size:11px; width:124px; height:30px; text-align:center; line-height:30px; color:#000; text-decoration:none; border:1px solid #fff; border-width:1px 1px 0 0; background:#ccc; font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif;}

#body .photo ul.topic li a ul, 
#body .photo ul.topic li ul 
{display:none;}

#body .photo ul.topic li.active a
{color:#000; background:#bbb;}

#body .photo ul.topic li a:hover,
#body .photo ul.topic li:hover a
{color:#fff; background:#aaa;}

#body .photo ul.topic li.active ul
{display:block; position:absolute; left:0; top:31px; list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; height:375px; background:#ddd; width:464px; padding:40px 60px; border:20px solid #bbb; z-index:1;}

#body .photo ul.topic li a:hover ul, 
#body .photo ul.topic li:hover ul
{display:block; position:absolute; left:0; top:31px; list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; height:375px; background:#ddd; width:464px; padding:40px 60px; border:20px solid #aaa; z-index:100;}

#body .photo ul.topic li ul li
{display:inline; width:112px; height:87px; float:left; border:1px solid #fff; margin:1px;}

#body .photo ul.topic li ul li a
{display:block; width:110px; height:85px; cursor:default; float:left; text-decoration:none; background:#444; border:1px solid #888;}

#body .photo ul.topic li ul li a img
{display:block; width:100px; height:75px; border:5px solid #eee;}

#body .photo ul.topic li a:hover ul li a:hover, 
#body .photo ul.topic li:hover ul li a:hover 
{white-space:normal; position:relative;}

#body .photo ul.topic li a:hover ul li a:hover img, 
#body .photo ul.topic li:hover ul li a:hover img 
{position:absolute; left:-50px; top:-32px; width:200px; height:150px; border-color:#fff;}
</style>






<div id="body">
<div class="photo">
<ul class="topic">
    <li><a class="set" href="#Portraits">Portraits<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait1.jpg"><img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/portrait1a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait2.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait2a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait3.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait3a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait4.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait4a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait5.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait5a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait6.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait6a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait7.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait7a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait8.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait8a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait9.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait9a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait10.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait10a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait11.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait11a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait12.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait12a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait13.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait13a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait14.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait14a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait15.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait15a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait16.jpg"><img src="lbox/portrait16a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>

    <li class="active"><a class="set" href="#Landscapes">Landscapes<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape1.jpg"><img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/landscape1a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape2.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape2a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape3.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape3a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape4.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape4a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape5.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape5a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape6.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape6a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape7.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape7a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape8.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape8a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape9.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape9a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape10.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape10a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape11.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape11a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape12.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape12a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape13.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape13a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape14.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape14a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape15.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape15a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape16.jpg"><img src="lbox/landscape16a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
    <li><a class="set" href="#Flowers">Flowers<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#flower1"><img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/flower1.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower2"><img src="lbox/flower2.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower3"><img src="lbox/flower3.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower4"><img src="lbox/flower4.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower5"><img src="lbox/flower5.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower6"><img src="lbox/flower6.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower7"><img src="lbox/flower7.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower8"><img src="lbox/flower8.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower9"><img src="lbox/flower9.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower10"><img src="lbox/flower10.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower11"><img src="lbox/flower11.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower12"><img src="lbox/flower12.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower13"><img src="lbox/flower13.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower14"><img src="lbox/flower14.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower15"><img src="lbox/flower15.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#flower16"><img src="lbox/flower16.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->

    </li>
    <li><a class="set" href="#Trees">Trees<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/tree1.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree2.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree3.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree4.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree5.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree6.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree7.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree8.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree9.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree10.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree11.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree12.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree13.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree14.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree15.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="lbox/tree16.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
    <li><a class="set" href="#Birds">Birds<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#bird1"><img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/bird1.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird2"><img src="lbox/bird2.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird3"><img src="lbox/bird3.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird4"><img src="lbox/bird4.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird5"><img src="lbox/bird5.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird6"><img src="lbox/bird6.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird7"><img src="lbox/bird7.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird8"><img src="lbox/bird8.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird9"><img src="lbox/bird9.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird10"><img src="lbox/bird10.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird11"><img src="lbox/bird11.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird12"><img src="lbox/bird12.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird13"><img src="lbox/bird13.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird14"><img src="lbox/bird14.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird15"><img src="lbox/bird15.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#bird16"><img src="lbox/bird16.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
        </ul>

    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
</ul>
<br class="clear" />
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a solution using Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.topic li a').click(function(){
        $('ul.topic li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    alert('hi') //Just for knowing everything is well!
    })
})​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/nQ2TK/1/

**To make this example works in your HTML page do the following:**

In the page head section:

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery-1.x.x.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

Then in the body section after body tag:

```
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul.topic li a').click(function(){
            $('ul.topic li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        alert('hi') //Just for knowing everything is well!
        })
    })​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
    </script>
...
</body>
```

Finally, you are able to get the latest jquery library from its [official website](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: How would I put that into my html file. I have never used jquery before. But thanks it works!

Comment: @user1815176 please look at the edited version of the answer.